# vb6 can not connect oracle 11g r2 with ADO but can connect with SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, vb6, database-connection, oracle11gr2

I can not connect Oracle 11g r2 with ADO in VB6. But I can connect Oracle database with Oracle SQL Developer with same parameter. How do I check this problem?
Here my connection string: (The password is hide)

```
connstr = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;dbq=[same name]:1521/[same name];Database=[same name];User Id=evo;Password=*****;"
```

and this parameter in SQL Developer (Sorry, I can't place my screen)

```
Connection Name: [same name]
User Name: evo
Password: ****** (hide)
Role : Default
Connection type : Basic
Host Name: [same name]
Port : 1521
SID :[same name]

What I do wrong?
Thank you.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install and configure Oracle Client. SQL Developer uses JDBC and seems to have a native driver.